# How to set up telnet in AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, telnet, putty

I got SSH working fine. But I am facing an issue with connecting via telnet.

[image: Outbound]

[image: Inbound]

[image: Putty]

Comment: does ` telnet <you ip address> 22 ` give the same result?

Comment: It is giving result like.. Escape character is '^]'. SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1

Comment: Connection closed by foreign host

Comment: is telnet service installed , ` sudo yum -y install telnet-server `. By default it is not installed.

Comment: I have installed telnet by "yum install telnet"

Comment: Now i am getting message like "Protocol mismatch", in 22 port

Comment: From 23 port "telnet:connect to address XX.XX.XX.xX : connection time out

Comment: Can you connect via telnet from the host itself? (in SSH session)

Comment: I tried connect from another connection.. it is not connecting

Comment: You need to install telnet-server , telnet is the client package

Comment: Yes i installed.. By using this command only sudo yum -y install telnet-server

Comment: Can you try the steps mentioned in http://aws-certification.blogspot.in/2016/01/install-and-setup-telnet-on-ec2-amazon.html?m=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ssh** is recommended over **telnet**, as **telnet** is not encrypted and is by default not installed in amazon instance.

However if needed, steps involved for Linux : Amazon Instance or Centos

1. **Install telnet daemon in the instance:** Install telnet-server using `sudo yum install telnet-server` . Package `telnet` is for the client program in case one want to connect using telnet client from the instance, not needed for the exercise.
2. **Enable the telnet daemon service:**
        -  By default the service is disabled in `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet`, The `disable` flag needs to be set to `no`.

   `service telnet
   {
           flags           = REUSE
           socket_type     = stream
           wait            = no
           user            = root
           server          = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
           log_on_failure  += USERID
           disable         = yes
   }`

   Post change it should look like below
   `service telnet
   {
           flags           = REUSE
           socket_type     = stream
           wait            = no
           user            = root
           server          = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
           log_on_failure  += USERID
           disable         = no
   }`

   Verify the configuration in case of any edit related errors.
   `sudo chkconfig xinetd on`
3. **Bring up the telnet service:**

   Bring up the telnet daemon as root using `sudo service xinetd restart` command
4. **Enable inbound telnet default port (23) on AWS Console:**
   In AWS Console `EC2/Security Groups/<Your Security Group>/Inbound`, set a rule

   `Type:Custom-TCP Rule`

   `Protocol: TCP Range`

   `Port Range: 23`

   `Source: <As per your business requirement>`
5. **Test the telnet connection:**
   Test the telnet connection from any client enabled in the firewall.

   `>telnet ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.region.compute.amazonaws.com.
   Connected to ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.region.compute.amazonaws.com.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   Password:`

The steps(tools) will vary slightly for other linux variants.

PS: Referred http://aws-certification.blogspot.in/2016/01/install-and-setup-telnet-on-ec2-amazon.html, fixed few issues in the commands.

Answer (score 50):

```
 sudo yum -y install telnet
```

This works for me after logging in to the EC2 instance

Comment: This works for adding telnet to an EC2 Linux 2 AMI.  Note, this does not set up a telnet server/service.  OP may have wanted the latter, but I wanted the former (simple telnet to another host to check if a remote port is listening).