# Err_connection_refused in amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am facing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` / `The site can't be reached` issue with my ec2 instance(Amazon linux ami)

When I used `telnet <publicIP> 80` it says

Trying 
telnet: connect to address : Connection refused

The security group is open to port 80 for Inbound
[image]

When I use `telnet <publicIP> 22` it hangs

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085886/how-to-set-up-telnet-in-aws-instance ?

Comment: It's the httpd which is not working. I tried starting the service but it failed. Just trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you want to just start a server, you need to enable a server on the machine (SSH). Then you can access your web server via IP (if that's what you want).
If you don't open a server, the connection will be refused.

Comment: Thanks. It's sorted now.It was the SSL certificate issue and that's why the apache service was not restarting.