# Can't Telnet into an AWS Public EC2 Instance (Linux) from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-prompt, telnet, aws-security-group

I'm trying to telnet into a newly created AWS Public EC2 Instance from my computer's command prompt. I've already set up this instance's Security Group as follows: [Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n52KM.png)

Other things to note is that its VPC is custom and that the instance is housed in a Public Subnet. I made this switch because I initially tried to ping this EC2 instance's public IP address, which works!

Additionally, I did the following:

1. Enabled Telnet on my computer via these steps - Open Windows Start menu > Type "Control Panel" > Press Enter > “Programs” > "Programs and Features" > Turn Windows features on or off > Select "Telnet Client" > Press “OK".
2. Installed the telnet server and client in this specific EC2 instance using the commands `sudo yum install telnet-server` and `sudo yum install telnet`. Now, I couldn't figure out why I still couldn't connect here despite disabling my Windows Firewall. I'm using the command, `telnet <EC2 instance's public IPv4 IP address> 23`.

What could be the issue?

I'm expecting to successfully telnet into the Public EC2 Instance from my Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: In addition to installing the telnet server, you'll also need to [enable and start the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088746).  That said, I would really recommend _not_ installing a telnet server, much less opening it up to the entire Internet.

Comment: Why do you want to use Telnet instead of SSH (which is more secure)?

Comment: The reason is that this is part of my lab assignment in a course.

Comment: @AnonCoward I tried this one but I keep encountering the error, `no such directory` when using `sudo chkconfig xinetd on`. Would you know how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Try `ssh` to the instance and run `telnet localhost`. What is the result?

Comment: Assuming the public subnet associated with IGW, 23 port is opened and allowed either anywhere or your own in your inbound rule then there shouldn't be an issue from server side. 
Have you tried to telnet and ssh from another EC2 either in the same or different subnets?

Comment: @Chachatonel Tried this just a few min. ago, it didn't work on the same Public Subnet.

Comment: I won't be trying any further as my professor has agreed to simply show the error messages. Although, I'm still curious as to why things aren't working the way they should...

Comment: Please share more details with the EC2 network if you're willing to debug yet.